# How to ask user to input FOLDER PATH in Tkinter Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I would like to know how to allow user to key in a folder path, so that when user key in the folder path, it will load all the text file in the folder. However, I would like to do this is Tkinter.

I understand that by using Python IDLE, the code is `raw_input`. I did some search about using it on tkinter, it stated that use something like `ask_directory`.

I tried to google `ask_directory`, however, I couldn't find any source of help on this.

Could anyone help me out regarding this?

On how to ask user to key in path folder and loop through every files in the folder.

Comment: `from Tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory` is what you're after. If you were having trouble finding out how, then you can also use the `dir` and `help` operators to find out.

Comment: You couldn't find _any_ help? When I google "tkinter askdirectory" I get over 4000 results. You're saying _non_ of those results were helpful?

Comment: yea, none of it is what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

To do this

```
from Tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
```

Then to get it go `path=askdirectory()`
The variable `path` now has the directory in it.